# Can we create subnets, route tables, and NSGs in virtual network resource blocks or subnet blocks using Dynamic in Terraform for Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Can we create subnets, route tables, and NSGs in virtual network resource blocks or subnet blocks using Dynamic in Terraform for Azure?

please let me know or can anyone provide code with short example.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each                                      = var.subnets
  name                                          = each.key
  resource_group_name                           = var.resource_group_name
  address_prefixes                              = [each.value.addressPrefix]
  virtual_network_name                          = azurerm_virtual_network.Virtual_Network.name
  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = each.value.privateEndpointNetworkPolicies
  private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = each.value.privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies
  service_endpoints                             = each.value.service_endpoints

  dynamic "route_table" {
    for_each = subnets.value.route_table
    content {
      name                          = route_table.value.name
      disable_bgp_route_propagation = route_table.value.disableBgpRoutePropagation

      dynamic "route" {
        for_each = route_table.value.routes
        content {
          name                = route.value.name
          address_prefix      = route.value.addressPrefix
          next_hop_type       = route.value.nextHopType
          next_hop_ip_address = route.value.nextHopIpAddress
        }
      }
    }
  }

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    addressPrefix                     = string
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies    = string
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies = string
    service_endpoints                 = list(string)
    route_tables = object({
      name                       = string
      disableBgpRoutePropagation = bool
      routes = list(object({
        name             = string
        addressPrefix    = string
        nextHopType      = string
        nextHopIpAddress = string
      }))
    })
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Azure subnets, route tables, security groups, and virtual networks can be configured with dynamic blocks in Terraform.

For example, here's how to iterate over the "subnets" variable from your question:

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    addressPrefix                     = string
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies    = string
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies = string
    service_endpoints                 = list(string)
    route_tables = object({
      name                       = string
      disableBgpRoutePropagation = bool
      routes = list(object({
        name             = string
        addressPrefix    = string
        nextHopType      = string
        nextHopIpAddress = string
      }))
    })
  }))
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_x" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.key
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.res_group_x.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vn_x.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.addressPrefix]
  service_endpoints    = each.value.service_endpoints

  private_endpoint_network_policies    = each.value.privateEndpointNetworkPolicies
  private_link_service_network_policies = each.value.privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "rt_x" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                = each.value.route_tables.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.res_group_x.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.res_group_x.name

  disable_bgp_route_propagation = each.value.route_tables.disableBgpRoutePropagation

  route {
    for r in each.value.route_tables.routes : {
      name                   = r.name
      address_prefix         = r.addressPrefix
      next_hop_type          = r.nextHopType
      next_hop_in_ip_address = r.nextHopIpAddress
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "rt_assoc_x" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet_x[each.key].id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.rt_x[each.key].id
}
```

In-line subnets are avoided above to limit nesting. "for_each" is used to iterate over the "subnets" variable since it's a map, and a "for" expression is used to iterate over routes since it's a list.

See docs for [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks), ["for" expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for), and [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet)

Comment: @ Leo Toff hi I have added my code in the question please check let me know is this works?

Comment: That's too specific for Stack Overflow, crosses the line into paid consulting. However, I'll try to do it if I have time.

Comment: @Mr.cool I updated my answer to iterate your specific data structure in the "subnets" variable. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Invalid block definition: Either a quoted string block label or an opening brace ("{") is expected here
route {
    for r in each.value.route_tables.routes {

Comment: What version of Terraform and Azure provider are you using?